# Word document page numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I have a Word 2013 (.docx) document and for some reason the page numbers have gone a bit loopy. I have a title page and then the main content. I have the following settings;

- In page number settings I have page numbering starting from 0
- In footer design I have "different first page" with no footer on the title page
- All other pages should then show page number

So; page 0 (title) displays as should - no footer, pages 1 and 2 display as should - their respective page numbers, but then what should be page 3 is showing page 1 in the footer.

I have tried fiddling with all sorts of settings but to no avail. As its quite an odd problem I wasn't really sure what details to post so if I have missed posting any crucial bits of info please comment and I will add it.

Comment: If you have a section break between pages 2 and 3, numbering will start over on page 3 unless you link the footer to the previous one.  I don't have access to Word right now for the exact terminology, but there is an option to continue numbering from the previous section.

Comment: @Jonny Wright, You can check if you have any section breaks by [turning on Formatting marks](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-or-hide-formatting-marks-c0460106-19d3-4441-986c-b655bffe6be4)

Comment: Thanks both, it was section breaks. Not sure how or why they were there mind.